# Minimize the "cost" of an array

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have an array A of size N. If I choose a number k, 0 <= k< N, the cost of an element A[i] is defined as:

> - if i < k then cost=max{A[i], A[i+1],...,A[k]}
> - if i = k then cost=A[k]
> - if i > k then cost=max{A[k], A[k+1],...,A[i]}

I need to find the k which minimizes the cost and that minimum cost.

> For example A = 3, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3
>  The minimum cost is 28 for
>   k=2 (A[2]=2)
>
> - max{A[0], A[1], A[2]}=3
> - max{A[1], A[2]}=3
> - A[2]=2
> - max{A[2], A[3]}=5
> - max{A[2], A[3], A[4]}=5
> - max{A[2], A[3], A[4], A[5]}=5
> - max{A[2], A[3], A[4], A[5], A[6]}=5
>
> cost=3+3+2+5+5+5+5=28

Comment: Sounds like a dynamic programming problem to me.

Comment: @Damien could you describe the simple algorithm?

Comment: @Primusa Sorry, I read the post too fast!! Very stupid

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in `O(N)`. Let's break down the problem.

The first thing we notice is that with a given `k`, the left and right sides of it are independent. We can break it down into three pieces: `left[k]`, which is the sum of the maxes for all `i` <= `k`, `right[k]`, which is the sum of the maxes for all `i` >= `k`, and `arr[k]`. In this case `cost(k) = left[k] + right[k] - arr[k]`. Note that `arr[k]` is counted once in `left` and again in `right` so we have to subtract it at the end.

We just need to understand how to compute `left` and `right` efficiently.

Some formal definitions:

Let `f(i, k)` be `max{A[i], A[i+1], ..., A[k]}`, and let `left[k]` be the sum of all `f(j, k)` for all `j` on `[0, k]`.

Let's consider each element that sums up to `left[k]`. We have a sequence like the following, where `left[k] = sum(sums)`.

```
sums = [max{A[0], A[1], ..., A[k]}, max{A[1], A[2], ..., A[k]}, ...,max{A[k]}]
```

Notice that this sequence is non-increasing. As a result we can model the sum we get with a *monotonically decreasing stack*. Let's see how:

When we make the transition from the sums of `left[i]` to `left[i + 1]`, we add `A[i + 1]` to the sums, and then we set each element in our sums less than `A[i + 1]` to `A[i + 1]`. Once we set that element to `A[i + 1]`, *it's original value doesn't matter anymore*.

We can take advantage of this like so. Let `stack[i]` be a tuple in the form `(value, multiplicity)`. We let our stack represent each component of our sum, such that

`left[i] = sum(value * multiplicity for value, multiplicity in stack)`. Note that this is also equal to `sum(sums)` from earlier.

Here's how we can update our stack as we add elements:

```
stack = []
for element in A:
    element_count = 1
    # while the previous element is less than this one
    # we merge it into this one
    while stack and stack[-1][0] <= element:
        element_count += stack.pop()[1]
    stack.append((element, element_count))
```

Notice that the total amount of work being done is `O(N)`, each element is added and removed from the stack once each, so there is `O(2N) = O(N)` work done.

To compute `left[i]`, we could take `sum(value * multiplicity for value, multiplicity in stack)` at each iteration, but this is very slow. Instead we can maintain a running sum as we add and remove elements from the stack:

```
stack = []
left = []
running_sum = 0

for element in A:
    element_count = 1

    while stack and stack[-1][0] <= element:
        v, mul = stack.pop()
        element_count += mul
        running_sum -= v * mul
    running_sum += element * element_count
    left.append(running_sum)
    stack.append((element, element_count))
```

We've just computed `left` in `O(N)`! We can use the same strategy on the reverse of the array to compute `right` in `O(N)` as well. Once we have `left` and `right`, we can compute `cost(k)` in `O(1)`, which lets us find the maximum `k` in `O(N)`.

Comment: Could you detail your algorithm on a simple example? I don't understand why `left` and `right` do not depend on `k`, but I am certainly missing something

Comment: @Damien they don't depend on k because left is an array with calculation for all k. Each specific index correlates to the the sum of all costs to the left of k if the k were that index. So each index is the calculation for the corresponding k.

Comment: So each left[i] is the calculation of the cost of each element to the left of i if k == i